# Parsing a character string of varying lengths

Tags: r, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string of estimated salaries to create a new field called "Salary.Min" which should be a numeric value. It seems straightforward and I can handle this in SQL with a quick case statement but I'm having trouble translating into R.

Do I need to use a for loop here or is there a more efficient/simple way? Generally I'm looking to do something akin to "if 4th character in string = K then return characters 2:3, otherwise return characters 2:4"

This code seemed to be okay at first but after validating I've realized it's eliminating all records where the 4th character = K (ie minimum salaries of $100k+)

```
>  ifelse(   
>    substr(data_public$Salary.Estimate, 4,4) == "K",
>        data_public$Salary.Min<- substr(data_public$Salary.Estimate, 2, 3),
>        data_public$Salary.Min<- substr(data_public$Salary.Estimate, 2, 4))
```

I have a wide range of Salary.Estimate values, a few for example:
a) $105K - $115K
b) $89K - $95K
c) $78K - $85K

Comment: The `data_public$Salary.Min<-` should be outside the `ifelse` i.e.  `data_public$Salary.Min<- with(data_public, ifelse(substr(Salary.Estimate, 4, 4) == "K",  substr(Salary.Estimate, 2, 3), substr(Salary.Estimate,2, 4)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could make this shorter with `trimws` and `substr`.  Here, we get the `substr`ing from 2 to 4 character and specify the `whitespace` in `trimws` as 'K' where the `which = 'right'` signifies to match for the trailing character

```
data_public$Salary.Min <- trimws(substr( data_public$Salary.Estimate, 2, 4), 
      which = 'right', whitespace = "K")
```

---

Or we could use `sub`

```
sub("^.(..)K?.", "\\1", data_public$Salary.Estimate)
```

---

In the `ifelse` code, the assignment should be outside the `ifelse`

```
data_public$Salary.Min<- with(data_public, 
          ifelse(substr(Salary.Estimate, 4, 4) == "K",
             substr(Salary.Estimate, 2, 3), substr(Salary.Estimate,2, 4)))
```